# QGis 3.22 - Pixelised Map Background

Tags: qgis, basemap

I've got a little problem and I'm out of ideas.

My map background is pixelised and I would like to find a solution.

The map I'm using is the reference in France (from the national geographic institute)

WMS link:

```
https://wxs.ign.fr/essentiels/geoportail/wmts?SERVICE=WMTS&REQUEST=GetCapabilities
```

This is the result:

[image: result of IGN WMS]

I already tried to launch another one from a raster and I've had the same result.

Most people doesn't seem to have this problem with the same WMS so I'm pretty sure it comes from my own system.

Comment: Did you try changing Rasampling method in layer styling?

Comment: Hi ! Thank for your answer ! I'll looking at this at least for learning, the solution was the tiles scales. Have a good day !

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The WMS layer you're loading in your QGIS is likely set-up to `EPSG:3857` so if you are using another SCR in your QGIS project the WMS layer is probably re-projected with a slight distortion !
If you change your QGIS project's SCR to `'EPSG:3857'` the quality of your WMS should get better !

Otherwise you can try to modulate the tiles scale (in the QGIS menu click on:
View > Panels > Tile Scales )

[image]

Comment: Hi ! Thank a lot for your answer !!! Tile scale was the solution ! Thanks again, it help me a lot !

Comment: Pas de soucis :)